# Ionic - How to create an alarm notification similar to incoming call or clock alarm

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, notifications, alarm

I'm creating an alert pager app by using Ionic(v1) framework, which the notification message is very important for user, and they don't want to miss it.

However the normal android / ios notification can only display the message on the screen + play notification sound once, which user always miss the messages.

Anyone can suggest if there's any way that can generate the notification similar to in-coming call or clock alarm, it can ring forever until user acknowledge the message by pressing the button, and that alarm notification screen can be displayed on standby mode as well?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't achieve that in iOS.

Comment: Thanks, even native app can't do it? Wondering how whatsapp can do it for incoming call?

Comment: VoIP apps have a different set of rules.  They can still be silenced (just like you can with phone calls) but they can use background audio to play an alert tone