# FCM onMessageReceived not calling Android

Tags: android, android-service, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am facing one problem while implementing FCM in Android application.

Everything works fine, my service `onMessageReceived()` is not calling. But I am getting following logs when I send a message from my Java Server.

```
    08-25 12:14:53.216 20482-20482/com.cognisun.sas D/ActivityThread: BDC-Calling onReceive: intent=Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE flg=0x10000010 pkg=com.cognisun.sas cmp=com.cognisun.sas/com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver (has extras) }, receiver=com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver@ac9047a
08-25 12:14:53.222 20482-20482/com.cognisun.sas D/ActivityThread: BDC-Calling onReceive end receiver=class com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver
08-25 12:14:53.223 20482-20482/com.cognisun.sas D/ActivityThread: BDC-RECEIVER handled : 0 / ReceiverData{intent=Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE flg=0x10000010 pkg=com.cognisun.sas (has extras) } packageName=com.cognisun.sas resultCode=-1 resultData=null resultExtras=null}
08-25 12:14:53.223 20482-20482/com.cognisun.sas D/ActivityThread: SVC-Creating service: CreateServiceData{token=android.os.BinderProxy@750442b className=com.cognisun.sas.services.firebase.MyFirebaseMessagingService packageName=com.cognisun.sas intent=null}
08-25 12:14:53.223 20482-20482/com.cognisun.sas D/ActivityThread: SVC-CREATE_SERVICE handled : 0 / CreateServiceData{token=android.os.BinderProxy@750442b className=com.cognisun.sas.services.firebase.MyFirebaseMessagingService packageName=com.cognisun.sas intent=null}
08-25 12:14:53.224 20482-20482/com.cognisun.sas D/ActivityThread: SVC-Calling onStartCommand: com.cognisun.sas.services.firebase.MyFirebaseMessagingService@6345088, flags=0, startId=1
08-25 12:14:53.225 20482-20482/com.cognisun.sas D/ActivityThread: SVC-SERVICE_ARGS handled : 0 / ServiceArgsData{token=android.os.BinderProxy@750442b startId=1 args=Intent { act=com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT pkg=com.cognisun.sas cmp=com.cognisun.sas/.services.firebase.MyFirebaseMessagingService (has extras) }}
08-25 12:14:53.227 20482-21308/com.cognisun.sas D/SettingsInterface:  from settings cache , name = cover_app_component , value = disable
08-25 12:14:53.227 20482-21308/com.cognisun.sas D/SettingsInterface:  from settings cache , name = cover_app_lock , value = 0
08-25 12:14:53.232 20482-20482/com.cognisun.sas D/ActivityThread: SVC-Destroying service: com.cognisun.sas.services.firebase.MyFirebaseMessagingService@6345088
08-25 12:14:53.233 20482-20482/com.cognisun.sas D/ActivityThread: SVC-STOP_SERVICE handled : 0 / android.os.BinderProxy@750442b
```

Any suggestions ????

This is my service class,

```
class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService() {
    internal var TAG = "FCM Message"
    override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage?) {
        Log.e(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage!!.getFrom())

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size > 0) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData())
        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody()!!)
        }
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml file,

```
<service android:name=".fcm.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService"
        android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>

<service android:name=".fcm.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

**I am getting the Notifications while the app is in the background. Problem occurs if application comes in foreground**

Comment: can you post manifest file ..

Comment: May help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45267335/create-an-repetitive-high-pitch-alarm-on-a-remote-trigger-when-app-is-not-runn/45406863#45406863

Comment: manifest added..

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options

Comment: While my app in background, I am receiving Notifications but while app in foreground i am facing problem

Comment: @JayVyas have u test that on all device or single device

Comment: Yes, In another device it also gives same issue.

Answer (score 3):

**First**, follow instructions from [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive) guide, they are very clear and easy, or you can clone sample code from [here](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/messaging) and see for yourself what is wrong.

**Secondly** have you read these comments regarding `onMessageReceived()`

```
// [START_EXCLUDE]
// There are two types of messages data messages and notification messages. Data messages are handled
// here in onMessageReceived whether the app is in the foreground or background. Data messages are the type
// traditionally used with GCM. Notification messages are only received here in onMessageReceived when the app
// is in the foreground. When the app is in the background an automatically generated notification is displayed.
// When the user taps on the notification they are returned to the app. Messages containing both notification
// and data payloads are treated as notification messages. The Firebase console always sends notification
// messages. For more see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options
// [END_EXCLUDE]
```

Look for following comment in this [class](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/b15aedca71160f3a172adb3880fb3d7c3d699204/messaging/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/fcm/MyFirebaseMessagingService.java#L81)

```
// Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
// message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
```

For more see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options

Answer (score 3):

Firebase will not call your `onMessageReceived()` when your app is in the background or killed, and you can't customise your notification. It will show notifications managed by Firebase it self.

to make Firebase library to call your `onMessageReceived()` in every case

> a) Foreground
>
> b) Background
>
> c) Killed

**Do not put JSON key "notification" in your request to Firebase API, use "data" instead**, see below.

For example, following message will not call `onMessageReceived()`

```
{
  "to": "/topics/test",
  "notification": {
    "title" : "title",
    "message": "data!"
   }
}
```

but this will work

```
{
  "to": "/topics/test",
   "data": {
       "title":"title",
       "message":"data!"
   }
}
```

see this it has a detailed description of firebase message type For example:

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
        sendNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("message").toString(),
             remoteMessage.getData().get("title").toString());
    }
}

private void sendNotification(String message, String title) {
    int requestID = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, activityCompat);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, requestID, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.small_logo)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message).setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                    .bigText(messageBody))
            .setTicker(messageBody);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationBuilder.getNotification().flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    Notification notification = notificationBuilder.build();

    notificationManager.notify(requestID, notification);
}
```

Comment: Make sense exactly!