# Notification showing Wrongly in Firebase android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Hi Here i write it using Firebase Notification,i am used onMessageReceived to get notification,and send it on sendNotification functionality,Here my problem is ,my app is sleep mode,when i click the notification i need to go main activity page,but i got error ,its started from splash screen Here is my code on Firebase Messaging  Service

```
public class FirebaseMessagingService extends com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService {
private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";
String data;
String jsonObject;

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom()); //MyFirebaseMsgService: From: 1055554437945
    // Check if message contains a data payload.


    data = String.valueOf(remoteMessage.getData());
    Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        jsonObject = remoteMessage.getData().toString();
    }
    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle()); ////MyFirebaseMsgService: Message Notification Body: Customer request for service
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase("Service Request")) {

            sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(), remoteMessage.getData().toString());
        }

    }
    // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
    // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
}

/**
 * Create and show a simple notification containing the received FCM message.
 *
 * @param messageBody FCM message body received.
 */
private void sendNotification(String messageBody, String values) {
    Log.i("messageBodymageBody", "" + messageBody);

    if (isUserLoggedIn()) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("values", values);
        intent.putExtra("identify", "1");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = stackBuilder
                .getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                        | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        startActivity(intent);
        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.fixmelogo)
                .setContentTitle("Service Request")
                .setContentText("Customer request for service")
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    } else {
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent1);
    }

}

public boolean isUserLoggedIn() {
    Log.i("bollcheck", "" + UserInformations.getUserInformations(this).getId() + UserInformations.getUserInformations(this).getEmail());
    /*if (UserInformations.getUserInformations(this).getId() != null || UserInformations.getUserInformations(this).getEmail() != null
            || UserInformations.getUserInformations(this).getMobile() != null) {*/
    return UserInformations.getUserInformations(this).getId().trim().length() > 0;
}}
```

and also my manifest file

```
 <application
    android:name=".App"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/fixmelogo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@drawable/fixmelogo"
    android:supportsRtl="true"

    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".Activity.SplashScreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name=".FirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name=".FirebaseInstanceIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/fixmelogo" />

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
        android:resource="@color/colorPrimary" />
    <activity android:name=".Activity.MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"/>
    <activity android:name=".Activity.TripActivity" />

</application>
```

when I click notification need to Main Activity, but it's going from splash Screen page, Sorry for my poor English, I am Beginner of the Android, kindly give some solution

Hi Here my Notification Json from Server

```
{
    "to":"d7XvGt8pD60:APA91bEjEe9IjhjJDmojvRDogMp1xc4sQFT9EcoB8TBvM-rCtkwryFhRVGvHIx1T6CWMoJu3l4UuaXgkgWrFj_Fo1SFhip9C-RXuthO6pfHvJ4GRQOipWtiVjUl9wtO7jfVd-T6jMBpJ",
    "notification":{
        "body":"Customer request for service",
        "title":"Service Request",
        "sound":"mySound"
    },
    "data":{
        "CustomerId":"99",
        "CustomerName":"Mayil",
        "CustomerLastName":"Kannan",
        "PhoneNumber":"96788484887",
        "PickupLocation":"Ponmeni Muniyaandi koil main road, Chandragandhi Nagar, Ponmeni, Madurai, Tamil Nadu 625016",
        "DropLocation":"Ponmeni Muniyaandi koil main road, Chandragandhi Nagar, Ponmeni, Madurai, Tamil Nadu 625016",
        "PickupLatitude":"9.92074762937605",
        "PickupLongitude":"78.0926296301913",
        "DropLatitude":"9.92074762937605",
        "DropLongitude":"78.0926296301913"
    }
}
```

they Are sending like this.

Comment: Post notification json which is being send from server

Comment: I've the same problem, with firebase, from last long, Meena, i also wait here for someone answers.

Comment: Please share your `FirebaseMessagingService.java` and notification json

Comment: hi i updated my notification json ,Kindly check it

Comment: @MeenaNarayanan please share `FirebaseMessagingService.java`

Comment: i shared @Maddy

Comment: check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45875859/fcm-onmessagereceived-not-calling-android/45880920#45880920

Comment: i put it already correct @Maddy Right??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157543/discussion-between-maddy-and-meena-narayanan).

Comment: Need to use BroadCast Receiver ??